# Can there be medium height(neither tall nor short) pea plants in Mendel's experiment?

Tags: genetics

Can there be medium height(neither tall nor short) pea plants in Mendel's experiment?

All textbooks I have read seem to imply that pea plants have to be either tall or short, nothing in between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Medium height (like in people) and other traits that seem like a mixture of two extremes are often a result of incomplete dominance. For example, a red and white flower are bred to produce an offspring with pink petals.

Mendelian genetics does not include incomplete dominance (which is classified as, surprisingly, non-Mendelian genetics).

Basically, Mendel got **very lucky** with his choice of plant. Pea plant height is strictly dominant, meaning one dominant allele results in tall plants, regardless of the identity of the second inherited allele. This is a consequence of the genetic makeup of pea plants. Had he tried a similar experiment with snapdragon flower color, he would be very confused.

(See https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~mcclean/plsc431/mendel/mendel2.htm for snapdragon incomplete dominance example.)

Comment: I don't think Mendel got lucky; I think he worked with these plants and on these traits specifically because he noticed the patterns in them.

Answer (score 0):

Because of law of dominance
Because dominant gene Express themselves and suppress effect of other gene . In case of pea  tall(t) is dominant and overrides effect of other recessive allele and does not even produces any intermediate trait.

Comment: Welcome. We require answers to be accompanied by suitable, credible answers. A little more detail and elaboration will help a lot too. It's more of a comment than an answer now.

Comment: I believe  AliceD was meaning to type: "accompanied by suitable, credible references".